# AttributeError: 'HttpWebRequest' object has no attribute 'delete'

Tags: httpwebrequest, webservice-client, delete-method

url = 'something'

headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/xml', 'Accept' : 'application/xml'}

request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
request.delete(url, headers = headers)

I am trying to call a delete menthod but getting attribute error - AttributeError: 'HttpWebRequest' object has no attribute 'delete'
Can someone help?